# How to resolve staleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in protractor?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

My app has more than 1 Login button, and it fails on 1st and 8th iteration out of 12 iterations while testing various features. Need suggestions to fix the code.   [image: Dom Snippet]

```
public async clickLoginMenu() {
    try {
        const button = await element(await by.buttonText('Login'));

           /* await browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].click()', await button).then(() => {
                browser.sleep(2000);
            });*/

            await browser.wait(until.presenceOf(await button), TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                'Unable to locate logout button.');
            await button.click();
        } else {
            logger.info('Cannot find the login button to click');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('Throw Exception error ' + e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is my working code:

```
public async clickLoginMenu() {
    try {
        const button = await element(await by.buttonText('Login'));
        if (await button.isDisplayed()) {
        await browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(await button), TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                'Unable to locate logout button.');
        await button.click();
        } else {
            logger.info('Cannot find the login button to click');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error('Throw Exception error ' + e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an `elementToBeClickable` wait in between the `presenceOf` and the actual `click()`

So:

1. Wait for presence
2. Wait for clickable
3. Click it

Comment: I tried but it went into infinite loop stating more than one element found by that locator. Then I changed it to CSS instead of ButtonText. It throws NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, #navbarmobile > div > button:nth-child(4))

Comment: I tried again with few changes. It did work! Thank you so much for the suggestion. Also, since it has more than one element with same buttonText name. Is it possible to select by index or some value ? elements.all and then filter through the elements find the first one etc..

Comment: yeah of course, you can always go like `element.all(by.css('.button')).get(index);`